# how to get data from file.txt into an NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have file.txt data file in my project which is in resource folder.

Now i need to fetch the data from the file and load it into NSMutableArray.

how to approach to it.

Comment: This depends on what the contents of file.txt look like. Depending on the content of file.txt you may have to open the file into an NSString and iterate through lines or something. If you have a say over the content of file.txt it may be an idea to change it to plist format instead, which can be read straight into an NSMutableArray.

Comment: apple,alpha,animal,apex,ball,bell,bat,bet,cat,cap,camel,cup,dog,dig,dim,dull,egg,enemy,fish,fly,gun,gap,girl,hen,hurt,happy,hello,ice,iron,jail,jam,jeep,king,knight,lion,lamp,large,monkey,money,management,nest,netscape,orange,onion,pen,pet,pot,queen,rat,rest,right,slight,seven,tiger,ten,umbrella,unwanted,van,vat,west,wrong,x-man,zibra,zoo this is my file content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to read the file. And the you need to separate the string in components.

```
    NSString *fileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"txt"] 
                                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                                        error:nil];
    NSMutableArray *stringsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[fileString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];

    NSLog(@"Array:%@",[stringsArray description]);
```

Good luck.

Comment: Your answer helped me,but my txt file contains values like "aaabd@cvb,afaf@vafah,afaf@fha"...I want only the value before @ symbol.I am aware of subStringToIndex,characterSet etc. techniques to check for special characters,but since it is array,I received compiler warnings!!